# knockout if binding to jquery mobile static header retains space

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout.js

My page has a static header (jqm) which is displayed conditionally depending upon a parameter. Well, the binding *is* working, i.e., it is being displayed conditionally, the page content **does not move up** when the header is **not** displayed.

I also tried css binding to set display none without luck.

html:

```
  <div class="home-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c" data-bind="if: isFish, style: {display:isFish()? 'block':'none'} ">
    <div class="logo" style="margin:0 auto;"></div>
  </div>
  <div>Content starts here</div>
  <div data-bind="text:count"></div>
  <div data-bind="text:isFish"></div>
```

javascript:

```
var viewModel = new function() {
  var self = this;

  if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
  } else {
    sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
  }

  self.count = ko.observable(sessionStorage.clickcount);
  self.isFish = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.count() % 2 ==0;
  });

}; //viewModel

$(document).ready(function() {
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
});
```

[Here's the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6npfpwru/31/).

Click on the "Run" button several times to see that the picture of the fish is hidden or displayed depending on count.

I want the line "Content starts here" at the very top when the picture is not displayed. How to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow, took me some time to grasp the actual issue, but that's a weird one. I found that on instances where it is *not* shown, if I resize the browser window even by 1 pixel, it'll jump up. The culprit is a `div data-role="page"` that is inserted by (I think) jquery-mobile, which has padding (both as an element style and from a class) causing that space to appear. - I'm no expert on jquery-mobile, but I'd hazard a guess you need to use `data-bind="css..."` and set an appropriate jquery class to hide the thing, as opposed to an inline style?

Comment: Yes, you're right. It will jump up if the window is resized and yes, data-role="page" inserts padding. I will try to use css binding to bind a class and hide that with jquery.

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this

```
<!-- ko if: isFish-->
<div class="home-header" data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-theme="c">
  <div class="logo" style="margin:0 auto;"></div>
</div>
<!--/ko-->
```

Comment: While it works in the fiddle, it does not in the actual jquery mobile environment. I have a background image stretched to fit the window and the bottom of the image gets cut off if I use this solution. Upvoting you for making it work in the fiddle.